# pg-promise , how to select with a where ... like date%

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Im a bit stuck trying to get a select of the following:

```
id(int)  balance(int)  datetime(timestamp without timezone)
7        153           "2020-08-24 20:15:49"
8        115           "2020-08-24 20:16:13"
9        105           "2020-08-24 20:17:14"
```

I want to select doing this

```
let date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
console.log(date) // 2020-08-24
let selectAddressSnapshotByDate = new PQ({text: "SELECT balance, datetime FROM table where datetime like '$1%' ", values: [date.toString()]})
```

I basically want to get the values whose datetime starts with the date value of the programm

Right now im receiving the following error:

> error: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown

Comment: `LIKE` is only for string values, not for dates or timestamps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, you are not using the query parameter properly. The parameter should not be surrounded with single quotes.

Then: if you want to deal with dates, then use date functions, not string functions such as `like`.

I would phrase your query as:

```
select balance, datetime 
from table 
where datetime >= $1::date and datetime < $1::date + '1 day'::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem happens because you have time info in form of TIMESTAMP but it requires you to have TIMESTAMPTZ. If it's any useful to you